# Автоматизация Андроид на Python

Tags: python, android, auto

**Меня интересует сброс настроек до заводских с включенными после него откладкой юсб и передачей файлов MTP**

У меня уже есть готовый скрипт для этого, но он не работает на устройстве huawei (скрипт который у меня имеется должен делать сброс, включение откладки, пропускать настройку телефона и включать передачу файлов MTP, но на huawei делает только сброс и включает откладку)

Скрипт написан на python, библиотека для автоматизации - poco

Прошу помочь знающих людей или хотя бы дать хоть какие то предположения как это сделать.